# Why is my compiler saying that my class type variable can't be modified?

Tags: c++, class, struct

Here is a snippet of the code I'm working on:

```
struct Entry
{
    string Key;
    string Values[maxValues];
    int valuesCount;
};

class CAList
{
private:

    Entry data[maxKey];

public:
    CAList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxValues; i++)
        {
            this->data->Key[i] = NULL;
            this->data->valuesCount = 0;
        }
    }

    const string* operator[](const string& Key) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxValues; i++)
        {
            if (this->data[i].Key == Key)
            {
                return this->data[i].Values;
            }
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < maxValues; i++)
        {
            if (this->data[i].Key == "\0")
            {
                return this->data[i].Values;
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
    
    void operator+=(const string& value)
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (this->data[i].Key != "\0")
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (this->data[i].Values[j] != "")
        {
            this->data[i].Values[j] = value;
            j++;
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    CAList tt, tt2, tt3;

    tt["alpha"] = "abc";
    tt["alpha"] = "def";
    tt["beta"] = "hij";
    tt["beta"] = "klm";

}
```

I want it to store a key and some values with it. It should have come as:

```
[alpha : {abc, def}, beta : {hij, klm}]
```

but it says two types of errors:

1. `E0137   expression must be a modifiable lvalue`

   This is for all places in `main()` where I am writing `tt[...]`.
2. `Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'const char [int]' to 'std::string *'`

   Again for all lines.

Comment: *Here is the code I'm working on, a snippet* -- No. Post a [mcve].

Comment: This is [what you posted](https://godbolt.org/z/rYz48K7rT).  A minimal, reproducible example would allow anyone to take the code you posted as-is, copy and paste it into their compiler editor, compile the code, and see the error or similar errors you are seeing now.

Comment: `string Values\[maxValues\];` doesn't compile.

Comment: `tt["alpha"]` has type `const string*`, `"abc"` has type `char[3]` so `tt["alpha"] = "abc";` is not legal because these two types are not compatible. I'd like to suggest a fix but the code is very confused and I can't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe you meant to write `tt["alpha"][0] = "abc"; tt["alpha"][1] = "def";`? That would be a little bit closer to being legal (but still not OK).

Comment: The code provided does not compile.  As-is, compiling the code produces different errors (which I suspect are due to missing `#include` directives).  When I fix the code so it compiles, I cannot reproduce the problem described.  I may have fixed the code such that I've incidentally fixed the problem that is being asked about.  Hard to say.  But I am certain that there are indeed bugs in this code.  A [mcve] would be most useful.  Help us help you.

Comment: You can't assign a value to a rvalue. The value returned by the function is rvalue not lvalue. Also the return value must be const char*.